# How to check if date column is earliest in said month for specific record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I'm pulling stock tickers and portfolios as well as a "PERIOD_END_DATE". As part of my query, how can I check if the PERIOD_END_DATE if the earliest in the month of said PERIOD_END_DATE column for that specific ticker and portfolio column, and if it is, return a specified column, otherwise return a custom calc? All i have so far is:

```
Select [Portfolio]
       ,[Ticker]
       ,[PERIOD_END_DATE]
       ,--if the period end date is the earliest in that month for the portfolio and ticker combo 
        --then return [TOTAL] otherwise return [CUSTOM_CALC]
from @SummaryTable_Collapsed
```

Sample Data:

```
Portfolio   Ticker  PERIOD_END_DATE Total
Portfolio1  Ticker1 2020-01-30  -1259940.57
Portfolio1  Ticker1 2021-01-28  -544665867.94
Portfolio1  Ticker1 2021-01-28  -66500068.29
Portfolio1  Ticker1 2021-01-28  -59720085.01
Portfolio1  Ticker1 2021-01-28  -19933126.67
```

Comment: Which dialect of SQL? :)

Comment: Your table schema, example data and desired results will help you

Comment: @Roelant Given the square brackets, it is likely either T-SQL or MS Access (and probably the former).

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this site. Using Microsoft SQL Server 2017. And how do I paste in table data? Every time I try i have to delete because it looks like hot garbage.

Comment: @ExpertGoogler: That is not easy indeed. Personally I prefer to use some example data with `INSERT INTO #some_temp VALUES ('first', 'second', 'third')`. You can find some examples on the internet - e.g. https://jackworthen.com/2018/05/17/creating-and-inserting-data-into-a-temporary-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Sample data would really help.  Is there some sort of date column?

Comment: Sample data is now added as well! @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your exact SQL, but I guess you can adjust. The general idea would be to first label these first rows, and then use this labelling.

```
WITH first_rows_labelled as (
     Select 
       [portfolio]
       , [ticker]
       , [period_end_date]
       , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY portfolio, ticker, date_trunc('month', period_end_date) 
            ORDER BY period_end_date ASC
         ) as row_of_month
     FROM @SummaryTable_Collapsed
)
SELECT 
    [Portfolio]
    , [Ticker]
    , [PERIOD_END_DATE]
    , case when row_of_month = 1 then total else custom_calc end as [output]
FROM first_rows_labelled
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's returning all 1 values for me. I added some sample data above to assist.